# Alerting user if certain word is entered but still allowing them to submit

Tags: javascript

So I have a list of entity names that have requested if we receive any mail for them that we scan it instead of send it via USPS. We log all mail into our records before sending it out to the client. What I want is for someone to type "mcdonalds inc" into the text box and hit submit then a pop up alerts them that this may be a flagged entity and if they would like to submit anyway. So I need to make sure that if certain words are entered into the text box the user is notified but also allowed to submit. Can someone please help? This is what I have so far.

```
document.getElementById('spe').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('spe').value;
    if (text.search('acar leasing') !== -1) {
        alert('potential watchlist');
    }
    if (text.search('XXX') !== -1) {
        alert('XXX is not allowed!');
    }
text = text.replace(/acar leasing/g,'');
text = text.replace(/XXX/g,'');
document.getElementById('spe').value = text;
},false);
```

Comment: Do you have a problem? Apart from `document.getElementById('spe').value = text;` being logic you problably don't want, your code works as you describe it.

Comment: Yes. When I hit ok to clear the alert it text box refreshes as well.

Comment: It's bad practice to use alerts. They block scripts and can cause unwanted behavior. 

You should create a HTML modal window that pops up with the message. Then you can assign a function there attached to a button that either submits the form or cancels it.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant that I don't understand the logic. As written you do this: "every time the user types a word inside the box, replace the 'forbidden' words with an empty string." So what is the goal? I assume that if the user still has to be able to send those words, you don't want to replace them with an empty string. Change their color? Have a seperate box containing the forbidden words that were typed?

Comment: Ok then how would I be able to change the color of the word instead?